# Product saleable qty not showing and update in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.2.3, magento2.3

[image]

where i can update the saleable quantity in magento 2.3 ..the above tab is showing blank.

And how to update saleable quantity programmatic

Comment: is it a fresh install? or an old installation migrated to the other server?

Comment: migrated from 2.1

Comment: products visible on frontend or not?

Comment: products are available in front end

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have same issue with resolved, take `inventory_source_item` table backup first.

Run sql query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `inventory_source_item` (source_code, sku, quantity, status)
select 'default', sku, qty, stock_status from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` as `lg` join `catalog_product_entity` as `prd` on((`lg`.`product_id` = `prd`.`entity_id`)))
```

Apply command:

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: I have `Inventory_stock_1` but some product not able to add in cart. Error: `Product that you are trying to add is not available.`

Answer (score 1):

In Magento v2.3

If you want to use MSI:

Check inventory_reservation

https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/wiki/Salable-Quantity-Calculation-and-Mechanism-of-Reservations

If you don't want to use MSI turn the All Magento Inventory Modules Disable :

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/install-extensions/inventory-management-installation.html#disable-inventory-management

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/inventory/index.html

IN DataBase There was two type

1> Tables and

2> Views

also The issue is possibly caused When Import/Export DataBase Views Was Not Created in magento 2.3 So check **Views** and **inventory_stock_1** table In DataBase.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason is that you did not assign your product to any Source.
As soon as the product would be assigned Magento would calculate Salable product Quantity automatically.

Read more about Salable Quantity calculation and Inventory Management in Magento 2.3 here - https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-management.html

Answer (score 1):

Answer by manoj pal above worked for me. The inventory_source_item table was empty and required one-time population.

After setting up Inventory Stocks/Sources in the back end, I observed these problems with my installation that needed fixing:

- You could not add a product to cart on front end. 'Product that you are trying to add is not available.'
- In the back-end, in the product table, the 'Salable quantity' column was *blank*, i.e. nothing showing in the table cell.
- In the back end, the 'Product Saleable Quantity' twistie on the product page was also blank. Nothing was visible.
- When saving a product in the back-end, I observed this error in the var/log/debug.log:

  Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails  CONSTRAINT `INVENTORY_SOURCE_ITEM_SOURCE_CODE_INVENTORY_SOURCE_SOURCE_CODE` FOREIGN KEY (`source_code`) REFERENCES `inventory_source` (`source_code`)), query was: INSERT INTO `inventory_source_item` (`source_code`, `sku`, `quantity`, `status`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `quantity` = VALUES(`quantity`), `status` = VALUES(`status`) [] []

Following instructions above by @manoj-pal fixed this, and I was able to add products to cart.

**However**, saleable quantity and the twistie was still blank in the admin back end! WTF. I then noticed the join table inventory_source_stock_link table was blank. Googling this took me to this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213282/salable-quantity-in-magento-2-3-dont-show

I saw how he inserted the missing row into table inventory_source_stock_link. Once I had populated this table, the back-end product pages started to display 'Salable quantity' in both the table cell and the twistie.

I must say MSI shows lots of promise and capabilities but this upgrade to Inventory Management has been quite a drama!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is possibly caused by **`the missing DB tables`** with connections/relations to the **`Product Table`**. 
The solution would be:

- Check whether **`All DB Tables`** (including data) from **`the old DB`** are all copied to the **`new DB Schema`**.
- Check if **`inventory_stock_1`** Table does exist and is filled with data relating to your Product Table.

Comment: I have seen the table  **inventory_stock_1** and data also there

Comment: check the `qty` it should not be blank or zero.

Comment: All products having the qty

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.3 you need to configure inventory sources in addition to adding product quantity. Check following 2 things:

1. Under Stores => Inventory => Sources you have at least one source available. If not then you found the problem. Add New Source with following (you can use different values here if you wanted):`Name: Default Source, Code: default, under Address Data, select your store country & provide a zip code / postcode`. Save & Continue
2. Under Stores => Inventory => Stocks, if you don't have any records then click on Add New Stock button, Add Name: Default Stock, Websites: select the website and click Assign Source. Now select the default source that we created earlier. Click Save

Reindex catalogue `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
and clear the cache.
This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was creating a new inventory source and assigning it to my products. Not entirely sure what the issue was but it was related to the default source created from the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, problem was in assigning products to **Source**.
Check `inventory_source_item` table in your DB. If you can't find your product(-s) by **SKU** - try to regenerate this table items manually.

**Warning** - *it might work only for single stores view.*

---

1. Make backup of your `inventory_source_item` table.
2. Check what **source_code** is using in this table for products, if it
   has rows.
3. Clear `inventory_source_item` table.
4. Use this sql query to generate sources for all your products.(change `source_code` value from `default` to yours, if needed)

> INSERT IGNORE INTO 'inventory_source_item'('source_code', 'sku',
>   'quantity', 'status') SELECT 'default', catalog_product_entity.sku ,
>   cataloginventory_stock_item.qty, 1 FROM 'catalog_product_entity' INNER
>   JOIN 'cataloginventory_stock_item' ON catalog_product_entity.entity_id
>   = cataloginventory_stock_item.product_id

*Make sure you use table prefix if needed.*

**Reindex** products

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

And **flush cache**

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```